# How to save clicked result in cookie or in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, local-storage

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link").click(function(){
        $(".elem").toggle(); 
    });
    $('.floating').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('.link').text(event.target.textContent);
        // document.cookie = "cookiename=event.target.textContent"; this doesnt working
    });
});
jQuery(function($){
 $(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
  var div = $(".link"); 
  var second = $('.elem');
  var close = $('.close');
  if (!div.is(e.target) 
      && (second.has(e.target).length == 0 || close.is(e.target))) { 
   second.hide(); 
  }
 });
});
// Cookies.set('cookiename','0blue'); also this one
```

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 1180px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.elem {
 display:none;
 margin-top: 14px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 310px;
 background-color: grey;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: 0.4s;
}
.elem:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;

 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-bottom: 10px solid grey;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;

 top: -10px;
 left: 33px;

}
.title {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 position: relative;
}
.link {
 margin-left: 13px;
}
.regions {
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.floating {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 line-height: 0.4;
 width: 20px;

}
a.floating {
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 24%;
}
a.floating:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.otherregion {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.edit {
 border:1px solid #9E9E9E;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 90%;
    height: 23px;
}
form {
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
.formtext {
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
}
.top {
 margin-left: 13px;
 margin-right: 38px;
}
.close {
 margin: -27px 0px 20px 444px;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 18px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Any project</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <a class="link" href="#">Countries</a>
 <div class="elem">
  <p class="title">Choose youre locality </p><i class="close" >X</i>
  <div class="regions"> 
   <a class="floating" href="#">Kiev</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Baku</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Paris</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">London</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Moscow</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Amsterdam</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Rome</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Dubai</a>
   <a class="floating" href="#">Berlin</a>
  </div>
  <p class="otherregion">Or choose another one:</p>
  <form>
   <input class="edit" type="text" name="add" placeholder="Начните вводить название">
  </form>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script><!-- This is my cookie  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cookie.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

First I need to understand why cookie don't setting in my browser. I  take another scripts and run it from my openserver and everything works great but if I write code like this

```
document.cookie = "cookiename=info123";
alert(document.cookie);
```

alert shows empty string. And in developer tools Chrome show empty line. Next I need when you clicked and choose(clicked) the any country from list of countries it must saved in cookie or in localstorage. If it's possible show me please both version, if you refresh browser or close browser it must be there. Instead of countries must be your choice. Please anyone help already week can't solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use localStorage.

```
$('.floating').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.link').text($(this).html());
   localStorage.setItem('cookiename',$(this).html());
});
```

Then to retrieve it

```
 var value = localStorage.getItem('cookiename');
```

Comment: KyleK thank you result saved in localStorage. but how to change this in browser?var value = localStorage.getItem('cookiename');
      value = $(".link"); this is wouldnt help me .

Comment: what?  I dont understand.  Ive provided everything you need.  Im setting it, and I showed you how to retrieve it when you need it.  What else is there?

Comment: If you mean setting the link class to the chosen value.  Then simply $('.link').html(localStorage.getItem('cookiename'))

Comment: KyleK i mean when user will close or refresh the browser  instead countries must be showed the result which he chose.

Comment: Yeah Ive provided how to get the value.  Its up to you to apply it to whereever you want.  I dont really see a select list or anything, so not really sure where you want to apply it.  But my example above, basically applies it to the link, on page refresh.  You'll obviously need some sort of default as well, if its not already set.  But I can't code the whole thing for you, cuz you have to figure some stuff out yourself. This site isn't meant to just write your site for you. You're going to have to be more specific when you say 'showed the result he chose'.  Where? what element? trigger click?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect. `document.cookie = "cookiename=" + event.target.textContent;`

Also ideally you'd want to set an expires date, otherwise the cookie would not exist after the browser is closed.

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + (<duration in ms>);
document.cookie = "cookiename=" + event.target.textContent + ";expires=" + dt.toUTCString();
```